# ASCII characters set

Tags: ascii, non-ascii-characters

I am reading a (.txt) file, the contents of first line are just the four alphabet letters: "abcd".
when I display the ASCII code of these letters, I expect I to find 97,98,99 and 100 respectively for a,b,c and b. But I found tow special characters which their ASCII code are 255 and 254 for ÿ and þ.
Therefore the length of read line is 6 not 4 because of "ÿþabcd". Are these special character must-to-insert at the start of any sequential text file or is there any way to avoid both of them?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: 0xFF followed by 0xFE is a BOM for UTF-16LE. However, if you saved that from a text editor then there are some problem with the editor, since in UTF-16 "abcd" must be 8 bytes long, making the whole file 10 bytes

Comment: Which language is your reader programmed in? Please tag your question and show some code.

Comment: I am using Visual Basic 6. The text file encoding is Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is only used in niche or archaic systems. Your data proved to you that your file is not ASCII. You must find out which character set and encoding the file was stored in.

## Character Sets

All text is an encoding of elements of a character set. Elements of a character set are called codepoints. A character set consists of a list of codepoints and their descriptions. The description states how the codepoint is used semantically in text, such as LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A ([A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/41/index.htm)) or N-ARY PRODUCT ([∏](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/220f/index.htm)). (The style in which the codepoint is rendered is the purview of typefaces/fonts.)

### Encodings

Codepoints are numbered with non-negative integers. The number is encoded into bytes. Most character sets have only one encoding, which is the number as an unsigned integer in the smallest size that can represent all of the codepoints. For example, Windows-1252 has 251 codepoints, with numbers between 0 and 255. A byte is big enough to represent any of them. The Unicode character set has about 1 million codepoints, numbered from 0 to 1,114,112.  A 32-bit integer is big enough to represent all of them. That's the UTF-32 encoding.

#### Byte order

Computer memory is usually byte-addressable and file are byte sequences so for a large integer the question becomes, in which order the bytes are stored: The most significant byte first (big endian) or least significant byte first (little endian). Software adapts to or assumes one way or the other. So, UTF-32 actually identifies one of two encodings: UTF32BE or UTF-32LE. UTF-32 is shorthand for the endianness that the software assumes. Typically, the OS assumes the endianness of the hardware it is running on and programs follow suit.

### Unicode Encodings

UTF-32 takes a lot of space. The most commonly used codepoints are numbered below 65,536. So there can be savings if codepoints are represented variable number of smaller integers. The size of the integer is called a code unit. The value of a code unit contains some of the bits of a code unit and indicates if there are more code units to follow that have more of the bits. So, there are UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE and UTF-8 (and more) encodings for Unicode. UTF-16 uses one or two 16-bit code units for a codepoint and UTF-8 uses one to four 8-bit code units for a codepoint.

Files are data outside of programs. So for a program to read text, it has to know the character set and encoding. Often this metadata is not stored with the file (within or beside). That's how you made the mistake of believing your file is ASCII. If you don't know the encoding of a file, you've lost data. You might be able to recover it through guessing. It is notable that the CP437 character set has 256 codepoints, numbered 0 to 255 and encoded in one byte. So every file can be read as CP437; The question is, is that right? Even if it looks right, it's probably not right unless it's from a Western culture circa 1990.

### Unicode Byte-order Mark

A strong clue about which character set and encoding to guess is called the byte-order mark (BOM). Recall encodings with code units larger than one byte have an endianness. Endianness is a hardware concern. So, although a file can be passed between systems with agreement on which character set and encoding scheme is used, the endianness attribute of encoding is critical to each system. It has become standard to indicate byte order within the file, as the first bytes. Unicode specifies a codepoint to use for this purpose, as long as it is at the beginning of the file. (That means that programs reading Unicode from a file must separate this metadata from the data.) Many file writing libraries write the BOM codepoint regardless of the code unit size. So, you'll see it at the beginning of UTF-8 files. Since the Unicode BOM looks different in each of the Unicode encodings, it completely identifies which Unicode encoding is being used.

## Guessing

**Your file begins with the UTF-16LE BOM.** Read it as UTF-16LE (and discard the BOM codepoint if your library doesn't already.)

Given the specificness of the Unicode BOM, its presence is a strong indicator that the file is encoded in Unicode and the actual bytes tell which Unicode encoding. However, as noted above, it's possible that this guess is wrong.

As @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc points out, it is unclear how you are reading "ÿþabcd" from what you say is a 6-byte file. Open the file in a hex editor. UTF-16LE should be FF FE 61 00 62 00 63 00 64 00.

Comment: it should be `FF FE 61 00 62 00 63 00 64 00` because the lower byte would be stored first

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Oops, that would have less than helpful for the question asker. Fixed. Thanks.